# Magento2.2.2: Module override cause in Wysywig editor shows broken image

Tags: image, magento2.2.2, wysiwyg, overriding

[image]
I have to override the Customer module.

**vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Indexer/Source.php**

in my custom module

```
app/code/Magenticians/Moduleproduct/Model/Indexer/Source.php
```

here is **registration.php** file :

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Magenticians_Moduleproduct',
__DIR__
);
```

in etc folder di.xml and module.xml file

...**di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source" type="Magenticians\Moduleproduct\Model\Indexer\Source" />
</config>
```

**module.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Magenticians_Moduleproduct" setup_version="1.0.1">
</module>
</config>
```

just add one function in **source.php** file

```
public function addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias = null)
{
   $this->customerCollection->addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias);
   return $this;}
```

override successfully. customer re-indexing has done.

but got an issue in `Wysywig editor` shows a broken image. which I insert in pages.

when I remove this overridden module Wysywig editor shows images properly.
I want to identify what's wrong with my module and why `Wyswig` show a broken image when this module is here?

Comment: complete module is here:

https://github.com/hafizjee/fix-customer-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check all php files of your custom extension and please check this 2 poinst.

1. Make sure that all php files start with `<?php` tag, with no space before it (most probably **registration.php**)
2. Check if all you php files does not have `?>` at the end of file, if yes, remove php close tag.

> app/code/Magefan/Moduleblog/registration.php
>
> app/code/Magenticians/Moduleproduct/registration.php

have empty line before `<?php` tag. Please fix it and it will work as expected.